# gobject introspection integration with autotools

Tags: gtk, autotools, glib, gobject-introspection

I would like to contribute to open source by enabling a library that builds with GNU's autotools to generate Gobject Introspection files.

A How-To to achieve this is already mentioned on the GObjectIntrospection's wiki page:

> Integrate GI in Autotools
>
> GObjectIntrospection/AutotoolsIntegration How to integration your library's build system with gobject-introspection

Unfortunately the link on the wiki page isn't working.

So how can I enable in an autotools project to generate a GIR file from a given header file set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki is undergoing some reorganization (projects are moving into a Projects/ directory).  That page is now at [Projects/GObjectIntrospection/AutotoolsIntegration](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection/AutotoolsIntegration).